# Are there some inequalities about $k\lceil{}x\rceil{}$ and $\lceil{}kx\rceil{}$

Tags: inequality

I wonder if there exist some inequalities about $k\lceil{}x\rceil{}$ and $\lceil{}kx\rceil{}$.

Note: $x$ and $k$ are positive rational numbers.

I have proven that if $k$ is an integer, then $k\lceil{}x\rceil{} \ge \lceil{}kx\rceil{}$. Here is the proof:

It's trivial that $k\lceil{}x\rceil{} = \lceil{}kx\rceil{}$ if $x$ is an integer.
For $x$ is non-integer,
we can represent $x$ as $m + \epsilon$ where $m$ is an integer and $0 < \epsilon < 1$, then $k\lceil{}x\rceil{} = k(m+1) = km + k$ and $\lceil{}kx\rceil{} = km + \lceil{k\epsilon}\rceil{} \le km + k$.

Comment: Is $k$ an integer? Is it positive?

Comment: $x$ and $k$ are positive rational numbers

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: if $k$ is an integer, then $k\lceil{}x\rceil{} \ge \lceil{}kx\rceil{}$

Answer (score 1):

I found the following equation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $n \neq 0$,
$\left\lceil\frac{x+m}{n}\right\rceil = \left\lceil\frac{\lceil x\rceil +m}{n}\right\rceil$ which is the generalized form of $\left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil = \left\lceil\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{n}\right\rceil$, we can rewrite the equation above as $ \left\lceil k {x}\right\rceil = \left\lceil k\lceil x\rceil\right\rceil$ with $k = \frac{1}{n}$.

Another inequality:
$$\lceil k x \rceil \le \lceil k \lceil x \rceil \rceil < k \lceil  x \rceil + 1$$
for any positive real numbers $k$ and $x$.